# How to write and/or call a jQuery plug-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to follow this article to write a simple jQuery plugin: http://brolik.com/blog/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/

I seem to always get the following error in my console:
[image: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).blogPost is not a function]

HTML

```
<div id="prod-part">TODO write content</div>
```

Javascript

```
(function($){
    $.blogPost = function(el, options) {
        var base = this;

        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        base.$el.data('blogPost', base);

        base.init = function(){
            console.log("hello");
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $('#prod-part').blogPost();

});
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle which still creates the issue.  I'm not sure If I am calling on the plug-in incorrectly or if the plugin is coded incorrectly.  I've tried jQuery versions 1.7.2 and 1.11.0 and still come out with the same results.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
http://jsfiddle.net/45oLp31m/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background:

The jQuery function (`jQuery()` or `$()`) acts as a factory to return a new instance of jQuery collection when you pass in a selector. So `$('#foo')` returns an instance of jQuery collection. In order to call methods off of that instance, like `$('#foo').somePlugin()`, those methods have to be defined on the instance. The primary way we get methods onto instances is to add them to the constructor's prototype.

## Solution

So the solution to your specific error is that jQuery plugins are defined on the jQuery collection constructor's prototype. This prototype is aliased at `jQuery.fn` (and `jQuery` is aliased as `$`, so `$.fn` is also ok). Adding methods to the prototype is as simple as `$.fn.somePlugin = function () {}`.

Thus your plugin needs to be defined like:

```
$.fn.blogPost = function(el, options) {
```

## More

As I said, this is for the *specific* error you quoted. I assume at this point that you haven't made it much further in your tutorial, so I won't go into the other issues in your code (like the fact that your plugin does not return the collection for chaining).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.blogPost = function(el, options) {...}
```

Try

```
$.fn.blogPost = function(el, options) {...}
```

Functions in the `$.fn` namespace are available as methods on jQuery collections, which is what you want.

```
$(selector).blogPost();
```

Such methods a generally known as "plugins".

In other (rarer) circumstances, you might want to extend the `jQuery` namespace itself, in which case your `$.foo = function() {...}` would be applicable. Such functions are known as "static methods".